# I am currently in graduate school but need to ask my previous professors for a letter of recommendation. I am worried this will be awkward

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, recommendation-letter, email

I just started grad school this semester. But as part of my stipend contract, I am required to continue to apply to scholarships (although I don't need to win them). I have not been in grad school long enough for my advisor to know my work (in fact, we haven't even started on the research yet). So I would have to ask the two professors I previously asked for a LoR last year to write me another one. But I am afraid this will be really awkward since I haven't spoken to them in months and I feel like I'm just asking them to do me favours now. Especially since they are already aware that I am in grad school, and I will just be asking them to write me another letter. How do I phrase this email to them to prevent the awkwardness?

Comment: It would seem that they would be able to easily adjust the letter that they already wrote for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you explain to them that this is part of your stipend contract that you are required to have these letters to apply to the scholarships, I am 100% sure noting that as well as a quick apology will eliminate any awkwardness.

Comment: I don’t think an apology is necessary; this is an absolutely normal request.